# Determine if an array changed after sorting

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I would like to determine if I should reload a TableView. When it appears, I do a simple sort based on names.

I could segue back to this view with more or less items in the dataSource, or a altered item in the data source that requires a re ordering of the cells. i.e., name changed from Foo to Bar, hence order change.

How do I determine if mutation of the list occurred after using the Swift sort method? I'm looking for something like this

```
let orderDidChange = clientList.sort({ $0.clientName < $1.clientName })
```

Here is my current code

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let originalList = clientList
    orderHasChanged = false

    clientList.sort({ $0.clientName < $1.clientName })
    clientList.sort({ $0.isBase > $1.isBase })

    orderHasChanged = clientList != originalList

    if orderHasChanged {
        // always enters here
        println("changed")
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    else {
        println("same do nothing")
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you just check `if originalList != clientList` after you sort?

Comment: You could, though I wouldn't recommend, even use `let orderDidChange = clientList != clientList.sorted({ $0.clientName < $1.clientName })`

Comment: I should have added that part of the dataSet is being saved using NSCoding, and then refetched. So the memory address - despite being the same object is now at the different memory location. So the == is not working (unless I've messed up) Maybe I need to implement equitable ?

Comment: Yeah, if what I have isn't working, then this is way over my head. I tried, but sorry I can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually just check if the old array equals the sorted array by using the `==` operator. If two arrays contain the same data, but in a different order, they are not equal.

For example,

```
let bar: [String] = ["Hello", "World"]
let foo: [String] = ["Hello", "World"]

//this will print "true"
//bar and foo contain the same data in the same order
print(bar == foo)


let bar: [String] = ["Hello", "World"]
let foo: [String] = ["World", "Hello"]

//this will print "false"
//bar and foo contain the same data, but in a different order
print(bar == foo)
```

So, something like this would work

```
let originalList = clientList
clientList.sort({ $0.clientName < $1.clientName })

let orderHasChanged = clientList != originalList
```

Comment: Works, just not for me in this instance.

Comment: @DogCoffee Try printing both arrays and see what your result is

Comment: I did a test and the compare works as expected as you show. But only when the memory address is the same. So when I save and re-init some objects they have a new memory address println("address: \(unsafeAddressOf(clientList.first!))") so they are the same essentially - but this invalidates the compare.

Comment: @DogCoffee I was able to get it to work [in a playground](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3WHaK.png), and both arrays have different addresses

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest I could think of. First you need to add a flag as a property then with the modified sort below where the flag is set based on if a sort had happened. If it hasBeenSorted then reload your tableView or not.

```
//private property
var hasBeenSorted = false

//var names = [3, 1, 4, 2]
var names = [1, 2, 3, 4]

names.sort({
    let isLess = $0 < $1

    //binary OR since we are interested only when it is true
    hasBeenSorted = isLess || hasBeenSorted 

    return isLess
})

hasBeenSorted //false
```